# Rewrite shell to Ansible task

Tags: ansible

How to rewrite shell task in to file module task

For example

```
  - name: Change permissions.
    shell: "chown -R {{ project_user }}:{{ project_user }} {{ project_root }}"
```

How to rewrite above code with the help of [file module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/file_module.html) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ansible - Mode 755 for directories and 644 for files recursively](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28778738/ansible-mode-755-for-directories-and-644-for-files-recursively)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's pretty simple:

```
- file:
    path: "{{ project_root }}"
    owner: "{{ project_user }}"
    group: "{{ project_user }}"
    recurse: true
```

Have a look at the examples: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/file_module.html#id3