# Ansible - Changing permission for all folders in path

Tags: ansible, permissions

In our playbooks we have multiple different paths which needs to have the same permissions.

I'm looking for a way how to change permissions for every folder in path so i.e. for `/opt/this/is/just/an/example` I need to change permissions for 5 folders (`this`, `is`, `just`, `an`, `example`). Only `opt` will be not changed.

The problem is that the paths can have different lenghts so there might be `/opt/something/else` in the future. These folders can contain other folders, not specified in our playbooks or files for which we cannot change permissions.

Do you know how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According the documentation [`file` module – Manage files and file properties](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_module.html) you may try

```yaml
- name: Change permissions for '/opt/this'
  file:
    dest: "/opt/this/"
    owner: 'user'
    group: 'group'
    recurse: true 
    # supposed to set directories to 755 and files to 644
    mode: u=rwX,g=rX,o=rX
```

**Thanks to**

- [Ansible: How to recursively set directory and file permissions](https://superuser.com/a/1694923/754490)
- [How to set file permissions on a tree in Ansible](https://superuser.com/questions/1431172/)
- [Ansible - Mode 755 for directories and 644 for files recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28778738/)