# Change permissions recursively on a directory structure takes too much time

Tags: ansible

I'd like to change the permissions on files recursively in a directory tree. The number of files are in the thousands.

I did the following right now on my playbook

```yaml
- name: find all the files inside the wordpress directory
  find:
    path: /home/vagrant/wordpress
    file_type: file
    recurse: true 
  register: files_found 

- name: Ensure permissions on folders are in 644
  file:
    path: "{{ item['path'] }}" 
    mode: '0644'   
  loop:   "{{ files_found['files'] }}"
```

This takes an "infinite" amount of time due to the large number of files in the directory structure.

- Is there any better alternative, especially in terms of speed of execution?
- Is the Ansible `command` module to execute a `find` `exec` command really the best alternative?

Comment: Could you just use the shell or command module and execute a find and chmod? `find /home/vagrant/wordpress -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;`

Comment: @Squashman in Ansible it is considered a bad practice to use `shell` or `command` if existing dedicated modules can do the job (and it most cases they can).

Comment: @U880D this will change the mode of the directory itself so it [will no longer be accessible](https://superuser.com/questions/1443639/why-cant-i-access-my-own-folder-with-permission-644).

Answer (score 1):

Since a solution with `file` module and `loop`,

- like in [How to set file permissions on a tree in Ansible](https://superuser.com/a/1431188/754490)
- or [Ansible - Mode 755 for directories and 644 for files recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60080913/6771046)

are not feasible because of

- [Why can't I access my own folder with permission 644?](https://superuser.com/a/1443640/754490)
- and furthermore the amount of files,
- as well the resulting execution performance and runtime,

one is currently left either with using the `command` module like in the advanced example

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Recursively ensure all file permissions in a directory are '{{ mode }}'
    ansible.builtin.command:
      cmd: find {{ path }} -type f -not -perm {{ mode }} -printf "%p\n" {% if not ansible_check_mode %} -exec chmod {{ mode }} {} \;{% endif %}
    vars: # "parameter" for the task
      path: '/home/vagrant/wordpress'
      mode: '0644'
    register: found_files # if there are any
    check_mode: false # in order to support ansible_check_mode on cmd
    changed_when: found_files.stdout_lines | length > 0 and not ansible_check_mode

  - name: Files {% if not ansible_check_mode %}changed{% else %}found{% endif %}
    debug:
      msg: "{{ found_files.stdout_lines }}" # or only var: found_files
    when: found_files.stdout_lines | length > 0 # otherwise skip
```

or

- writing a Custom Script or Custom Module

---

Some explanation regarding the `command` task ...

- [The notation used](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence) is to make it somehow look like other tasks
- To speed it up and [provide idempotency](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_intro.html#desired-state-and-idempotency) it search only for files which do not have already [(`-not`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1342110/6771046) the permission [(`-perm`)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/144270/266568) set
- It prints out the files found with full path [(`-printf "%p\n"`)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/215236/266568) to `STDOUT`
- It changes the permission for files found only
- So it `register` the found files which permission have changed
- It supports [`--check` mode](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_checkmode.html#using-check-mode) and perform permission changes only `{% if not ansible_check_mode %}`, otherwise it only report the file names found
- It reports only [`changed_when`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#defining-changed) there were files found, otherwise `changed: false`

Since the behavior of the task comes already close to a Custom Module it might not be feasible to invest resources into a separate Custom Module or enhancing existing modules with the requested functionality.